# How to know when a put on Cloud Datastore in App Engine reaches Milestone B?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have an application that uses Cloud Datastore via App Engine to save data.

I need to refresh the clients when an object is put on the database. To do it, after the object is put on the database, the server sends a sync message to the clients. The clients read the sync message and does a query to the server. The server does a Query to return the new result.

The problem is that when the Query is done, the put object doesn't appears on the query results. Reading the documentation, I suppose that the reason is that the put isn't on the Milestone B, see https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/transaction_isolation, because another later call object appears.

How can I know when a put reaches a "Milestone B"? If it isn't possible to know it, how can I do this logic (refresh clients after put)?

Comment: Are you using transactions?

Comment: Yes, but occurs the same

Answer (score 1):

You can ensure up-to-date query results by using an ancestor query, or, if you know the key of the specific entity you need to retrieve, you can fetch it by key rather than using a query.

[This page](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/structuring_for_strong_consistency) discusses the trade-offs of using ancestor queries.

Comment: My problem is that the saved object has a "when" field that is used to filter the objects between to dates. I'm thinking about how could reestructure  the object to do a parent-child relationship with the "when" field, but I can't find any solution. Any ideas?

Comment: @mabg - add your data model in the question (include keys, properties used to query and the query itself). This information is needed to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

The data do not appear in the result of your query because the indexes have not been updated yet. 
There is some latency before the indexes will be updated and unfortunately there is no way to know when this will happen.

The only way to handle this case is to use the entity's key, that is the only index that guarantees to be updated as soon the entity it's stored.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities

Comment: yes, the problem are the indexes. Somebody with the same problem, how resolve it?

Comment: you could also exploit ancestor queries:

Comment: The only filter that guaranties always fresh and updated results a query on ID, on Class Type and Ancestor Queries. You will need to change the structure of you data to make it accessible using these limitations. Also remember that the Entity ID can be a custom string and you could use this feature to solved your problems by using specific custom ID and query the entities over the IDs.